# Error when trying an angular.forEach inside a .then() function

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, datepicker

I receive correctly this nice array of json from my angularJs factory, from my php server-mysql backend . It is  some rendez-vous with a start date:

```
   [{"id":"1","title":"Loi Travail","infos":null,
     "adresse":"12 avenue des lis 78013  paris",
     "criticite":"4","fichiers":null,
     "start":"2017-06-11T22:37:59.012Z"},
    {"id":"17","title":"jjtyjyjt","infos":"jytjjyjyj",
     "adresse":"tjtyjjyj","criticite":"7","fichiers":"",
     "start":"2017-06-11T22:37:59.012Z"}]
```

The problem is that angular-material-datetimepicker doesn't recognise the start date, because it is a string, so i need to do a loop to add `new Date()`, for converting each of my "start" elements.

So, i've done this short code :

```
rdvFactory.get_rdvs().then(function(data){ 
    console.log(data.data);

    angular.forEach(data.data),function(value,index){
        console.log(value.start); 
    }
}).finally(function(){})
```

BUt my console.log shows nothing, and instead i've got this <del>strange</del> error :

> TypeError: b is undefined
>       Trace de la pile :
>       q@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:7:481
>       @http://localhost/rdvjuristes/app.js:61:2
>       h/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:134:467
>       $digest@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:145:417
>       $apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:149:111
>       l@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:102:87
>       wg/https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:107:489
>        Possibly unhandled rejection: {}

Do you think it is related to a $q thing ? Maybe there is another way for converting the dates ?

Thank you a lot if you have an idea, have a good day.

Just for information, if i type this, then the calendar displays well the rendez -vous(Please have a look at new Date())  :

```
$scope.events = [{"id":"1","title":"Loi Travail","infos":null,
                  "adresse":"12 avenue des lis 78013  paris",
                  "criticite":"4","fichiers":null,
                  "start":new Date("2017-06-11T22:37:59.012Z")}]
```

Comment: `angular.forEach(data.data),function(value,index)` should be `angular.forEach(data.data, function(value,index)`

Comment: THank you a lot it is working now , you are so good ! And the refused "strange" word made me laugh hi hi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to **[`docs`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)**, Change

**From**

```
 angular.forEach(data.data),function(value,index){
        console.log(value.start); 
}
```

**To**

```
 angular.forEach(data.data,function(value,index){
        console.log(value.start); 
 });
```

Comment: THank you a lot it is working now , you are so good ! And the refused "strange" word made me laugh hi hi